# How can I return the total of each unique donation category from an array of donations?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have an array of gift objects, which includes a date, name of the fund the donor gave to and the amount given. I want to total the amount given by each fund and return an object the fund which had the most giving as well as the total given to that fund, if there is a tie, I would like to return both of them.

```
 donations = [
 {
      donateTo: "BaseCamp",
      amount: 1000,
      date: "12/19/2014, 08:40"
 },
 {
      donateTo: "Where Most Needed",
      amount: 3000,
      date: "12/12/2014, 08:40"
 },
 {
      donateTo: "Where Most Needed",
      amount: 2000,
      date: "12/11/2014, 08:40"
 }
 ];
```

So if I run the above mentioned method against this array it should return

`{ donateTo: "Where Most Needed", total: 5000, count: 2}`

Also, I am using MongoDB to store these values, so if there is a way to aggregate this in Mongo, that would be great.

I'm using MongoDB with Meteor so if there is a way to get this using an #each or #with I'd be happy to do that as well, I'm just not sure if I'll need a javascript function exclusively or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
db.donations.aggregate([
{$group : {  _id: '$donateTo', total : {$sum : "$amount"}, count: { $sum: 1 }}},
{$sort: {total: -1}},
{$project : { '_id' : 0, 'donateTo' : '$_id', 'total' : '$total', 'count' : '$count'}},
{$limit: 1} ]).result[0]
```

Comment: I tried this and it doesn't seem to be working. I get an output of 
     ```{
          "total" : 3400,
          "count" : 1,
          "donateTo" : "Philippines Infrastructure"
     }```

I know for sure by manually looking through the collection that this isn't what should have come out on top.

Comment: for your sample documents I have : {
    "total" : 5000,
    "count" : 2,
    "donateTo" : "Where Most Needed"
}

Comment: If I remove this part ```,
{$project : { '_id' : 0, 'donateTo' : '$_id', 'total' : '$total', 'count' : '$count'}},
{$limit: 1} ]).result[0]``` and run it again I get this array. https://gist.github.com/c316/f642f378713110fca7be

Comment: Thanks for your help and your very quick answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use the [grouping](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) feature in MongoDB to aggregate those values. Check out the examples on that page as well.